# Finding Taylor's expansion for $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x} -\sqrt{ 1 - x}$

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I know I have to find the derivatives of $ f(x) $ (i.e. $f'(x)$ ..) but I'm confused about what to do afterwards .

Answer (score 3):

Expanding Christian Blatter's answer,
$\sqrt{1+x}
=(1+x)^{1/2}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}x^k
$.

For the first few coefficients,
$\binom{1/2}{1} = \frac12$,
$\binom{1/2}{2} = \frac12\left(\frac{-1/2}{2}\right) = \frac{-1}{8}$,
$\binom{1/2}{3} = -\frac18\left(\frac{-3/2}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{16}$,
so
$\sqrt{1+x}
=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16} \pm ...
$.

Putting $-x$ for $x$,
$\sqrt{1-x}
=1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{16} \pm ...
$.

Subtracting,
$\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}
=x+\frac{x^3}{8}\pm ...
$.

If you want the full series,

$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}x^k-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}(-x)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}(x^k-(-x)^k)\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}\\
\end{align}
$

since
$x^k-(-x)^k = 0$ if $k$ is even
and $2x^k$ if $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: For any $\alpha\in{\mathbb C}$ one has the binomial series
$$b_\alpha(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\alpha\choose k}\>x^k$$
which represents $(1+x)^\alpha$ for $-1<x<1$ and the principal value of $(1+x)^\alpha$ for complex $|x|<1$. The generalized binomial coefficients appearing here are defined by
$${\alpha\choose k}:={\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)\over k!}\qquad(\alpha\in{\mathbb C},\ k\geq0)\ .$$